# Logging all click events in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to reliably log each click event in javascript? 
Even if there is a more specific selector that has a click handler which
calls stopPropogration or preventDefault, I want to be able to log this click.

My goal is to be able to log all user clicks on my website, regardless of what content there is and what other programmers do. Essentially, intercept an event, log it, and call it's original handler. I'd like to have the overhead be as minute as possible.

Comment: This simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFgvb/) demonstrates that the two current answers (@Rottingham and @highwingers) *do not* work as specified by the OP.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7F7yT/, but I was cringing as I wrote it.

Comment: you can register a click event to the document object it will be called for all click events except for once where the propagation is stopped

Comment: @JasonP, that does work. Is that breaking a JavaScript rule? Use of *?

Is there a way to query all event bindings and update them?

Comment: It's not breaking any rules that I know of, but it could be alot of click events being added to a page. There is no way to query event bindings in Javascript (you could look at the `onclick` property to see if assigned, but that doesn't help if assigned by `addEventListener` or inline event handling), but jQuery (and other libraries) do keep a list of the ones assigned by their own methods.